# Is this derivation I did for the expansion of $\cos (\alpha+\beta)$ correct and how can I get rid of the $\pm$ symbol in it?

Tags: trigonometry

I derived the expansion of $\cos (\alpha + \beta)$ as follows, please take a look :

[image: Figure - 1]

Here, $\angle AOB = \alpha$, $\angle BOC = \beta$, $\angle AOC = (\alpha + \beta)$, $a = \cos \alpha$, $b = \sin \alpha$, $m = \cos \beta$, $n = \sin \beta$, $x = \cos (\alpha + \beta)$ and $y = \sin (\alpha + \beta)$.

Something to be noticed : $a^2 + b^2 = m^2 + n^2 = x^2 + y^2 = 1$ as they all are *sines* and *cosines* of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $(\alpha + \beta)$ respectively. These equations will be used  further in the derivation.

Now, from the above diagram,  we can find the length of chord $BC$ using the distance formula which states that the distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ on the *Cartesian Plane* is : $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$. So, we get :
$$BC = \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+a^2-2ax+y^2+b^2-2by} $$$$ = \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)+(x^2+y^2)-2ax-2by} = \sqrt{2-2ax-2by}$$
Now, what I do is rotate the axes by an angle of $\alpha$ anticlockwise to obtain this :

[image: Figure - 2]

[The dotted lines represent the old axes whereas the red lines denote the new axes. The new *X-Axis* coincides with the line segment $OB$].

Now, the length of chord $BC$ will remain the same irrespective of the position of the coordinate axes.

And, the point that was previously $B(a,b)$ is now $(0,1)$ and the point that was previously $C(x,y)$ is now $(m,n)$ because $\beta$ becomes an angle in standard position, so the point where the terminal side of $\beta$ will intersect with the unit circle will be $(\cos \beta, \sin \beta)$, which as I mentioned earlier, can be written as $(m,n)$ because $m = cos \beta$ and $n = \sin \beta$.

So, in this "new axes plane", the length of what previously used to be $BC$ will now be :
$$\sqrt{(m-1)^2+(n-0)^2} = \sqrt{m^2+1-2m+n^2} = \sqrt{(m^2+n^2)+1-2m} = \sqrt{2-2m}$$

Now, from the two values of the length of $BC$ that we have obtained by aligning the coordinate axes at two different positions are : $\sqrt{2-2ax-2by}$ and $\sqrt{2-2m}$. We can equate these two values to arrive at the value of $x$, which will give us the value of $\cos (\alpha + \beta)$.
$$\sqrt{2-2ax-2by} = \sqrt{2-2m}$$.
By squaring both sides, we obtain :
$$2-2ax-2by = 2-2m$$
Now, we can cancel the term $2$ on both the sides to obtain this :
$$-2ax-2by = -2m$$
Dividing both sides by $(-2)$, we will obtain :
$$ax+by=m$$
$$ax+b\sqrt{1-x^2}=m$$
$$b\sqrt{1-x^2} = m-ax$$
By squaring both the sides, we will obtain :
$$b^2(1-x^2) = (m-ax)^2 = m^2+a^2x^2-2max$$
$$\therefore b^2-b^2x^2 = m^2+a^2x^2-2max$$
Now, we can convert this equation to the standard quadratic equation form $(Ax^2+Bx+C)$ and obtain this :
$$(a^2+b^2)x^2+(-2ma)x+(m^2-b^2)=0$$
Here, $A = a^2+b^2$ which is equal to $1$, $B = -2ma$ and $C = m^2-b^2$

Let $D$ denote the discriminant.
$$\therefore D = B^2-4AC = B^2-4C = 4m^2a^2 - 4(m^2-b^2) = 4m^2a^2 - 4m^2 + 4b^2$$
$$\therefore D = 4(m^2a^2-m^2+b^2) = 4(m^2a^2-m^2+1-a^2) $$$$ = 4(a^2(m^2-1)-1(m^2-a^2)) = 4(m^2-1)(a^2-1)$$
$$\therefore D = 4(-n^2)(-b^2) = 4n^2b^2 $$$$ \implies \sqrt{D} = 2nb$$.
Now, by applying the quadratic formula,
$$x = \dfrac{-B \pm \sqrt{D}}{2A} = \dfrac{2ma \pm 2nb}{2} = ma \pm nb$$
From this, we get our final result,
$$\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta \pm \sin \alpha \sin \beta$$

Now, the only problem seems to be the $\pm$ symbol. How do I get rid of that and determine which symbol to actually put in its place?

Also, please let me know about your thoughts on the derivation.

Thanks!

Comment: Set $\beta=-\alpha$ to obtain: $1=\cos^2\alpha\mp\sin^2\alpha$. What sign do you choose? :)

Comment: Positive!! That was a good example. But, I do have a question. Is there a way to rule out the negative sign without examples? I just find drawing conclusions from examples *a little* ambiguous (this particular example is good compared to others, though).

Comment: Wrong! Negative (in your formula it is opposite). Here example is a good friend, as you should choose one possibility from two. It is similar to choosing positive square root if one computes a distance.

Comment: I don't get how it'd be negative, can you please elaborate? Thanks for the second part of your comment.

Comment: The correct sign in your formula is "$-$": $$\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta.$$ Substituting $\beta=-\alpha$ you will obtain $1=1$ [remember $\cos(-\alpha)=\cos(\alpha), \sin(-\alpha)=-\sin(\alpha)$].

Comment: I do get that. But, isn't $sin^2\alpha + cos^2\alpha = 1$? Also, why did you use the $\mp$ symbol instead of the $\pm$ symbol?

Comment: I changed it because $\sin(-\alpha)=-\sin(\alpha)$ (see above).

Comment: I get it, feels silly now. When it's positive, the result is negative, and when it's negative, the result is positive, hence $\mp$, right? Also, did you like the derivation? Have you seen it somewhere else too?

Comment: For me the proof is too complicated. I like simple ones. The result you are trying to derive can be obtained in one line using Euler formula for $e^{ix}$ and complex arithmetic.

Comment: Well, it was actually comparatively simpler for me. I have none to little knowledge knowledge about complex numbers. All I know is that $\sqrt{-1} = \iota$ and how to evaluate a natural exponent of $\iota$. I just began with $11^{th}$ grade Mathematics and the curriculum starts like this : Sets, Relations, Functions, Measurement of Angles (angle systems, mostly), Trigonometric Functions, Graphs of Trigonometric Functions and then, values of Trigonometric Functions at sum and difference of angles. So, I only have knowledge of these chapter and the topics covered till $10^{th}$ grade.

Comment: For me it looks nice.

Comment: Thank You for helping me! :)